# DynamoDB Query by Prefix of Partition Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, dynamodb-queries

I have a dynamodb table with following GSI:

- partition key: `scheduled_date` which is a date string `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`
- range key: `task_id` which is an uuid

I would like to query for all items whose `scheduled_date` falls in a date, i.e. its prefix matches a string `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Is it possible without performing scan?

Comment: `Is it possible without performing scan?`, No.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.KeyConditions.html

> You must provide the index partition key name and value as an EQ
> condition.

In your case, you could consider using `yyyy-mm-dd` (or `yyyymmdd`) as the partition key to get all of the items that have that scheduled date.

You could keep `task_id` as the Range key OR you could use a prefix like `HH:MM:SS:task_id`. That way the tasks for a particular day would come back sorted by time. And if you really needed to you, could query them by time range.

There is also the alternative of using Global Secondary Indexes that can be utilized in a similar manner.